# I need a way to increment a value in cypress code

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to automate a sign up scenario.
In sign up form, I have an email address field which is unique.

I'm using this code:

```
cy.get('#e_mail',{timeout:10000}).type('mpataz.tsc+1@gmail.com')
```

In next run am change the value in the email to be `+2` and so on in each run.

Is there a way to make the value increment automatically in each run?

Answer (score 3):

you can get uniq number by using `new Date().getTime();` it will return uniq number every time with reference to the current Date

```
const timestamp = new Date().getTime(); //1642080371822

cy.get('#e_mail').type(`mpataz.tsc+${timestamp}@gmail.com`)
```

instead of hardcoded timeout you can extract it and add to global `defaultCommandTimeout` inside `cypress.json`

```
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use faker js library to generate unique email id's.

After installing the faker js npm package, At the top of the spec file write:

```js
const faker = require('faker')
```

Then in your tests write:

```js
cy.get('#e_mail',{timeout:10000}).type(faker.internet.email())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your emails unique, I'd suggest doing using a timestamp with `Cypress._.random()` to generate the email each time.

```
const timestamp = String(+new Date()).slice(5)
const email = `test-email+m${timestamp}_${Cypress._.random(5)}@email.com`
```